# ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in Devise::SessionsController#create

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

Ошибка:

> ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken in
>   Devise::SessionsController#create
>   ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken

Начала появляться после того, как я разделил в Rails шаблон на две темы. По крайней мере я эту проблему заметил сейчас... Разделял так (ApplicationController):

```
prepend_view_path("app/themes/#{theme_name}/views")
```

В целом по на страницах сайта все впорядке. Другие формы работают отлично. Проблема только с авторизацией Devise. Регистрация Devise работает нормально.

Если в форме авторизации написать неправильный пароль, то она успешно отправится и выведет сообщение об ошибке (неверный пароль).

В чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема действительно была в:

```
prepend_view_path("app/themes/#{theme_name}/views")
```

У меня `prepend_view_path` обернут в метод, а метод вызывался почти в самом начале `ApplicationController` - после `layout`.

Короче говоря, лучше ничего вроде `before_action` не размещать выше:

```
protect_from_forgery with: :exception
```

Иначе это делает "больно" таким важным гемам, как Devise.